# Iterator to last element in std::list

Tags: c++, stl

```
#include <list>
using std::list;

int main()
{
    list <int> n;
    n.push_back(1);
    n.push_back(2);
    n.push_back(3);

    list <int>::iterator iter = n.begin();
    std::advance(iter, n.size() - 1); //iter is set to last element
}
```

is there any other way to have an iter to the last element in list?

Comment: for some reason, I don't want to have a reverse_iterator.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Yes, you can go one back from the end. (Assuming that you *know* that the list isn't empty.)

```
std::list<int>::iterator i = n.end();
--i;
```

Comment: In places this can be shortened as in `newlist.splice(--newlist.end(),oldlist);`

Comment: Also... 
 std::prev(std::end(list))

Answer (score 88):

Either of the following will return a `std::list<int>::iterator` to the last item in the `list`:

```
std::list<int>::iterator iter = n.end();
--iter;
```

```
std::list<int>::iterator iter = n.end();
std::advance(iter, -1);
```

```
// C++11
std::list<int>::iterator iter = std::next(n.end(), -1);
```

```
// C++11
std::list<int>::iterator iter = std::prev(n.end());
```

The following will return a `std::list<int>::reverse_iterator` to the last item in the `list`:

```
std::list<int>::reverse_iterator iter = std::list::rbegin();
```

Comment: Will `std::list<int>::iterator iter = --n.end();` work as well or the decrement will be done only after the assignment?

Comment: @mbrandalero it should work fine. The result of the decrement will be assigned to the variable

Comment: @RemyLebeau That might not always work (i.e. for iterators more generally, not just class-type ones), as iterators are not required to be modifiable lvalues. See [Why can't I decrement std::array::end()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48187786/why-cant-i-decrement-stdarrayend) for good discussion. So, basically, wrapping it in `std::prev()` is better style.

Comment: @mbrandalero *If* using predecrement is usable for a given iterator (see above comment), the decrement **must** be done before the assiignment, as that is how the entire world expects prefix operators to work, and any iterator not doing that would be dismally broken.

Answer (score 11):

With reverse iterators:

```
iter = (++n.rbegin()).base()
```

As a side note: this or Charles Bailey method have constant complexity while `std::advance(iter, n.size() - 1);` has linear complexity with list [since it has bidirectional iterators].

Comment: Why "++n.rbegin()" ? To me that seems like a reverse iterator to the next to last element. Wouldn't "n.rbegin().base()" (without the "++") be the iterator to the last element ?

Comment: @JoséX. base() is not just shorthand for casting an reverse iterator into a forward iterator. Take a look at this response for more info about base: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16609146/153861

Answer (score 7):

Take the `end()` and go one backwards.

```
list <int>::iterator iter = n.end();
cout << *(--iter);
```

Comment: Why do I have to go one backwards? Is there a dummy end node or something?

Comment: @Tarion: n.end() doesn't point at the last element, but right off the end of the list.

Answer (score 6):

```
std::list<int>::iterator iter = --n.end();
cout << *iter;
```

Comment: Prefix operators on rvalue iterators will only work in some cases and are not required to, so you should instead use `std::prev()`; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678175/iterator-to-last-element-in-stdlist#comment91853941_2678214

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own functions to obtain a previous (and next) iterator from the given one (which I have used when I've needed "look-behind" and "look-ahead" with a `std::list`):

```
template <class Iter>
Iter previous(Iter it)
{
    return --it;
}
```

And then:

```
std::list<X>::iterator last = previous(li.end());
```

BTW, this might also be available in the boost library ([next and prior](http://www.boost.org/libs/utility/utility.htm#functions_next_prior)).

Comment: This is available in C++0x as well (`std::next` and `std::prev`).

Answer (score 0):

```
list<int>n;
list<int>::reverse_iterator it;
int j;

for(j=1,it=n.rbegin();j<2;j++,it++)
cout<<*it;
```

Comment: Explaining the code you posted would make your answer even better.