# c++ stl what does base() do

Tags: c++, vector, erase

I have such code :

```
vector <int> v;
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
        v.push_back(i);
v.erase(find(v.rbegin(), v.rend(),2).base());
```

This code deletes the first element from vector v after first detected 2 (in vector remain: 0 1 2 4).
What does .base() do here?

Comment: Maybe you should read this : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/reverse_iterator/base/

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`base()` converts a reverse iterator into the corresponding forward iterator. However, despite its simplicity, this correspondence is not as trivial as one might thing.

When a reverse iterator points at one element, it dereferences the previous one, so the element it *physically* points to and the element it *logically* points to are different. In the following diagram, `i` is a forward iterator, and `ri` is a reverse iterator constructed from `i`:

```
                             i, *i
                             |
    -      0     1     2     3     4     -
                       |     | 
                       *ri   ri
```

So if `ri` logically points to element `2`, it physically points to element `3`. Therefore, when converted to a forward iterator, the resulting iterator will point to element `3`, which is the one that gets removed in your example.

The following small program demonstrates the above behavior:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> v { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    auto i = find(begin(v), end(v), 2);

    std::cout << *i << std::endl; // PRINTS 2

    std::reverse_iterator<decltype(i)> ri(i);
    std::cout << *ri << std::endl; // PRINTS 1
}
```

Here is a [*live example*](http://ideone.com/FV8c8d).

Comment: It appears the diagram does not match the code. In the code `i` points to `2`, but the diagram shows that `i` points to `3` (at least on my browser).

Comment: @aafulei The diagram refers to the situation in original question, where the `3` was being removed. The code is a separate example.