# Finding the maximum index of the biggest element of an array/vector

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

Currently I'm only aware of the following:

```
vector<int> nums= {3,2,1,0,2,3,3,1,0,0}; 
return max_element(nums.begin(), nums.end())-nums.begin();
```

But in that case it would return the lowest index of the maximum element.

A way around it would be:

```
vector<int> nums= {3,2,1,0,2,3,3,1,0,0}; 
int n = *max_element(nums.begin(), nums.end());
for(int i=nums.size()-1; i>-1; i--){
    if(nums[i]==n) {
       return i; 
       break; 
    }
}
```

But is there any simpler way that I can achieve the same result without bruteforcing it?

Comment: Pull up the documentation on std::vector and review the iterators it provides. The index from iterator calculation (which I overlooked you making at first) will also need to be adjusted when you change the iterators you use.

Comment: FYI, your `break` statement has no effect.  Once the `return` is executed, no other statements in the function are executed (because it returned).

Comment: Sort the array by ascending order.  Largest elements will be at the end.  The index of the largest element will be the index of the last element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate backwards by using reverse iterators, and get the distance:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> nums= {3,2,1,0,2,3,3,1,0,0}; 
    auto iter = std::max_element(nums.rbegin(), nums.rend()).base();
    std::cout << std::distance(nums.begin(), std::prev(iter));
}
```

Output:

```
6
```

See what [base()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16609041/c-stl-what-does-base-do) does when it comes to reverse iterators.

Comment: Care should be done for empty vector . `std::prev(iter)` would be UB. (but unclear which value is expected in that case anyway).

Comment: Very interesting, thank you! @PaulMcKenzie

Answer (score 2):

Whereas [`std::max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) returns the first largest element, [`std::minmax_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) returns the last one (for the largest).

So you might do:

```
std::vector<int> nums = {3,2,1,0,2,3,3,1,0,0}; 
return std::distance(nums.begin(),
                     std::minmax_element(nums.begin(), nums.end()).second);
```