# Get references to the last two elements in std::list

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, stl, iterator

I need aliases of the last two elements in an `std::list`. The last one is easy (`.back()`), but how should I get the one before it?

My first idea was: get an iterator after the last element (`.end()`) and the move it twice to the left. And here is what I "produced":

```
&last_but_one = *----myList.end(),
```

Although it works, I personally find it some kind of obfuscated and I don't think I would parse it easily if I saw it in someone else's code<sup>1</sup>.

Reading through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2678214/3132718) shows some other (too) verbose approaches<sup>2</sup>:

```
auto iter = n.end();
std::advance(iter, -2);
&last_but_one = *iter; // this is overkill!

// weird, and the .next() variant even more
&last_but_one = *std::prev(std::prev(n.end())); 

&last_but_one = *++myList.rbegin(); // similar to *----myList.end()
```

Which is the prefered way of doing this?

<sup>1</sup>I could leave a comment but code should be self-explanatory.
<sup>2</sup> and probably slower and more complex, which shouldn't be the main reason for the choice

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`std::prev()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev) takes two arguments. You can use the second one:

```
auto& second_to_last = *std::prev(list.end(), 2);
```

This does exactly what your version with `advance(iter, -2)` does, except it returns the resulting iterator instead of being `void` so you can do everything you need on one line.

Comment: Well, that's something I didn't think of, should have checked the docs. Looks pretty nice. And passes perfectly to my situation. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, from the [notes section](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev#Notes): "although the expression --c.end() often compiles, it is not guaranteed to do so..." you could add this to your answer.

Comment: @Al.G. For `std::list<>`, you're not going to get an iterator that's a pointer.

Comment: @Barry Well, there can be a ref-qualified `operator--`. Or a free one taking `iterator&`.