# Why can't I decrement std::array::end()?

Tags: c++, iterator, language-lawyer, stdarray

I'm creating a convenient `display()` function template for container types. The output for the last element is different from the rest, thus I check when `myIterator != --cont.cend();`. This works for `std::vector`, but won't work for `std::array`. Why?

Here's a MWE (not my actual code):

```
std::vector<double> vec({1,2});
std::array<double, 2> arr({{1,2}});
auto vecIt = --vec.end(); // OK
auto arrIt = --arr.end(); // error: lvalue required as decrement operand
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how the iterator is defined.

It seems that for the class template `std::array` the iterator is defined as a pointer. So the functions begin, end. cbegin, cend return just the pointer. Thus as the pointer is returned by value you may not decrease it because an `lvalue` is required..

For the class template `std::vector` the iterator is defined as a user-defined class for which the operator --() is defined.

Consider the following demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

class Int
{
public:
    Int( int x = 0 ) : x ( x ) 
    {

    }

    Int & operator --()
    {
        --x;
        return *this;
    }

    friend std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &os, const Int &i )
    {
        return os << i.x;
    }
private:
    int x;
};

int f( int x )
{
    return x;
}

Int f( Int x )
{
    return x;
}

int main() 
{
    std::cout << --f( Int( 10 ) ) << std::endl;
//  error: lvalue required as decrement operand
//  std::cout << --f( 10 ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Take into account that you can write

```
auto arrIt = std::prev( arr.end() );
```

instead of

```
auto arrIt = --arr.end();
```

provided that you include header `<iterator>`.

You can use the operator with the reverse iterators of the class template `std::array` because the Standard defines them explicitly like

```
typedef std::reverse_iterator<iterator> reverse_iterator;
typedef std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator> const_reverse_iterator;
```

and the user-defined class `std::reverse_iterator` defines the `operator --()` .

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main() 
{
    std::array<double, 2> arr = { { 1, 2 } };

    auto it = --arr.rend();

    std::cout << *it << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That was very instructive. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 16):

Since this is [language-lawyer](/questions/tagged/language-lawyer), [[expr.pre.increment]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.pre.incr#1.sentence-2) and [[expr.post.increment]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.post.incr#1.sentence-2) both have the restriction that:

> The operand shall be a modifiable lvalue.

Now, neither `vec.end()` nor `arr.end()` are lvalues, but both of their types are implementation-defined (for [array](http://eel.is/c++draft/array#overview-3) and for [vector](http://eel.is/c++draft/vector#overview-2)). In both cases, a simple pointer would satisfy all the iterator requirements for those containers - and this would be a type that uses builtin prefix- and postfix-increment. In that case, `--c.end()` would be ill-formed due to the restriction cited. Howver, if the iterator type is a *class type*, the restriction above doesn't apply - since we're not using the builtin increment operators - and invoking `operator--()` on a class does not have this restriction on it (though it could, if the member function were lvalue-reference-qualified).

So `--c.end()` for either vector or array isn't guaranteed to work, since if `end()` returns a pointer, this is ill-formed, and `end()` is allowed to return a pointer. On your particular implementation, `vector`'s `iterator` has class type but `array`'s `iterator` is just a pointer type, which is why the former works but the latter doesn't.

Prefer `std::prev(c.end())`, which will work for both container types for all implementations.

Comment: More basically, the iterator requirements do not require `--` to work on any iterator rvalue.

Answer (score 7):

Never decrement an rvalue, even if it happens to compile. It's unintuitive for readers of the code.

Use `std::prev` instead.

```
auto it = std::prev(arr.end());
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a fact of life from the C++ standard.

`--T.end()` is required to work if `T` is a `std::vector`, a `std::list`, or a `std::deque`. This was correct up to and including C++11; there have been relaxations subsequent to that.

Comment: Huh, do you have a citation for that?

Comment: There's something here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322104/how-portable-is-end-iterator-decrement

Comment: Interestingly, that table 68 which lists `vector/list/deque` and having that optional ability has been changed in C++14 (table 101 in `23.2.3 Sequence containers`) to *include* `array/basic_string` as well. It would be interesting to see if OP gets the same problem with a C++14 or better compiler.

Comment: It looks like the most recent draft, N4713, has resolved DR355, removing the accidental implication that `--c.end()` needs to compile. So this answer is no longer correct for more recent C++ versions. You can decrement the end iterator still (for bi-directional sequences), but not necessarily if it's an rvalue.

Comment: @SebastianRedl: Looks like I've stumbled on something more complex than I had originally thought. (I had it in my head from the when I learnt C++ formally - way back in C++03.) I've wiki'd if folk want to make contributions to the answer.

Comment: @SebastianRedl LWG DR355 was resolved [in April 2004](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1629.html), almost 14 years ago. Somebody is a little late to the party...