# Why does --string::end() compile but --string.size() does not?

Tags: c++, decrement

The code

```
std::string str{ "foo" };
auto lastCharIndex{ --str.size() };
```

creates a compiler error `lvalue required as decrement operand` but

```
auto lastCharIterator{ --str.end() };
```

does not. Why is this?

Comment: Because `string::end()` is a `string.iterator()` and has a defined `operator --()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I decrement std::array::end()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48187786/why-cant-i-decrement-stdarrayend)

Comment: Also relevant: [how portable is end iterator decrement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5322104/364696)

Comment: because they are two different function. they do different thing. (yes, this is for `string`, but generically functions can return anything, they may simply return a const object (with overloaded `operator--`) and you still cannot decrements it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to add that you *can* customize user-defined member functions like `++` that behave differently when called through lvalue and rvalue references. For example, you could define a custom `iterator` class that prevents you from calling modifying member functions on a temporary. To do this, you need to use [reference qualifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21052377/whats-a-use-case-for-overloading-member-functions-on-reference-qualifiers).

```
class iterator {
public:
    iterator operator++() & { // for lvalues
        std::cout << "incrementing...\n";
    }
    iterator operator++() && = delete; // for rvalues
};
```

With these qualifiers, you still allow lvalues to be modified:

```
iterator it = ...;
++it; // totally fine
```

but you can now prevent temporaries from being modified, which results in a user-defined class that is more consistent with built-in types like the `size_t`.

```
++(iterator{}); // ERROR
```

[Live example here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f3d4cdb5f487a1ae)

I'm not sure what the standard says about this for `std::string`'s iterator type, but in principle, you could do this for your own iterators and other classes, wherever you think it's always an mistake to modify a temporary.

Answer (score 4):

`string::size` returns a scalar type (some kind of integer), by value, and the built-in prefix-`--` expression is not allowed on prvalues. By contrast, for *overloaded* operators (on user-defined types), which are essentially just functions, no such restriction applies. Whether `--str.end()` is allowed therefore depends on whether `string::iterator` is a user-defined type (some sort of class type) or a scalar type (e.g. a pointer). This is not specified, though, and may even vary depending on optimization settings.

Answer (score 1):

The operand of the decrement (and increment) operator for fundamental types arithmetic types must be an lvalue. `std::string::size` returns a value (i.e. not a reference) of an integer type, so the function invocation `str.size()` is a prvalue. Prvalues are not lvalues, so `--str.size()` is ill-formed.

The operand of the decrement (and increment) operator overload for a class type may be called on an rvalue unless the overload is lvalue ref-qualified. If `--str.end()` is well-formed, then we can deduce that the iterator is a class type (pointer would be an example of a iterator type that is not a class type) and the decrement operator overload indeed does not have a lvalue ref-qualifier. As far as I can tell, whether member functions of iterators of standard containers are ref-qualified is unspecified.

P.S. Same applies to (compound) assignment operators: The **l**eft hand operand of an assignment must also be an lvalue (unless it is a class type with an overload that is not lvalue ref-qualified). In fact, this is where the "**l**" in **l**value originates.